# C++ invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|

Tags: c++

I have a problem with this code:

```
void keylist(char key)
{
   //check if the user presses a key
   if(GetAsyncKeyState(key))
   {
      string skey = key;
      buffer.append(skey);
      counter++;

   }
}
```

Everytime I try to run the program it gives me this error:
CodeBlocks Projects\CB32KLG\main.cpp|66|error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|

Answer (score 6):

It's because of this

```
string skey = key;
```

There's no overloaded constructor in string which only takes character as its input.See below the complete list:-

```
string();
string (const string& str); 
string (const string& str, size_t pos, size_t len = npos);  
string (const char* s); 
string (const char* s, size_t n);   
string (size_t n, char c);  
template <class InputIterator>
  string  (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

To fix you can use:-

```
string skey(1, key);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  string skey = key;
```

There is no viable converting constructor in `string` that takes just a `char`.
Initialize it like this:

```
string skey{key};
```

Or this:

```
string skey(1, key);
```

Comment: Anoter (somewhat surprising) option is to use `string skey; skey = key;`. Initialization is not permitted, but assignment is (and being chars integers it also means that's perfectly legal `std::string s; s=3.14;`)