# How to get sub-strings from a string using two delimiters (; and .) in C++

Tags: string, c++11, substring

I have a user input of this kind:

```
A+B*C;
A*(B+c);
C+F.
```

Now I want to parse this input and get all sub-strings until the semi-colons and stop scanning when I run into a period symbol.

What is the simplest way to achieve this ?

Also, I have freedom to take input from a file or from the console. Which one would be the easiest to implement ?

I have a method to read from the console as such :

```
cout << "Enter input: " << endl;
char delimiter = '.';
string inputStr;
getline(cin,inputStr,delimiter);
cout << inputStr;
```

But if I enter the above mentioned sample input I read only until before period symbol is recieved. So while finding sub strings, what stopping criteria or flag should I take ?

TIA

**EDIT:1**

Code so far:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter input: " << endl;
    char delimiter = '.';
    string inputStr;
    getline(cin,inputStr,delimiter);
    cout << inputStr;
    string deli = ';';

    size_t pos = 0;
    string token;
    while ((pos = inputStr.find(deli)) != std::string::npos) {
        token = inputStr.substr(0, pos);
        std::cout << token << std::endl;
        inputStr.erase(0, pos + deli.length());
    }
    std::cout << inputStr << std::endl;
};
```

**ANSWER:**

I was wrongly initializing the string `deli`. I had to do this :

`string deli = ";"`. Instead of single-quotes, I had to use double-quotes, because it a string and not a character! Final working solution here: https://repl.it/EPyC/2

Comment: After you do getline(cin,inputStr,delimiter); why dont you pass the inputStr to another function parse_by_semicolon(inputStr) which does what you need? ofcourse you have to write the algorithm to parse the inputStr by `;` now

Comment: thanks @solti for looking into it. Please see my updated question. I have the above mentioned algorithm but I get an error there: `main.cpp:13:19: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
     string deli = ';';` . You can test my code here: https://repl.it/EPyC/0

Comment: Okay error solved! This post helped : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816229/c-invalid-conversion-from-char-to-const-char-fpermissive

Comment: `string deli = ';';` should be `string deli = ";";` because its string and not a char

Comment: Got it @solti! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `getline` with delim `;` for all lines. Check for dot(.) for last line.

```
string line;
while(getline(cin, line, ';')){
    if(line.back() == '.') 
        line.pop_back();
    cout << line <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I could have more than 3 inputs too!

Comment: In that case, your sample input should look like `A+B*C;
A*(B+c); //...;
C+F.`

Comment: Wait..You are doing too many things. Reading all lines in one string, then finding delimiter, extracting substring, erasing sustring and all this inside a `loop`. Think of all this in readability perspective. You are over killing the problem!

Comment: What would you suggest then ? In fact on top of the things you mentioned, I am also pushing it inside a vector to store it for further processing. Here is the updated version: https://repl.it/EPyC/5 ! I have a problem there, my vector doesn't print out the last input token ? Do you see anything wrong?

Comment: I tried your suggestion here: https://repl.it/EPyW/0 , But it doesn't seem to come out of the while loop ?

Comment: How do I break the loop ? Any idea ?

Comment: It seems to work within the Ideone environment. Not anywhere else :( I am using Visual Studio 15, and it doesn't break out from there too!